# Singletone classes injected by dagger with synchronized methods

Tags: synchronized, dagger

I use singletone classes, are injected by dagger. But if  synchronized methods start running, but they terminates. But if I remove synchronization from methods, they run well.
If I inject sungletone classes by dagger, I shouldn't use synchronized methods?

Answer (score 4):

Dagger and Dagger 2 singletons and scoped providers use [internal double-checked synchronization](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/internal/DoubleCheck.java). If you're writing a singleton @Provides method, it will be called exactly once in a synchronized environment, so you probably won't need to worry about it.

Unless your `@Provides` method does anything thread-unsafe and is expected to be called multiple times, don't worry about marking anything `synchronized`.